# 80s (or earlier) anime, boy raised by a robot finds out that he has an evil brother who was also raised by a robot

Tags: anime, story-identification

It was probably around 1982 or so when I watched this anime a couple of times at my uncle's house. Can't remember the name and have been searching ever since.  My uncle passed away (20 years ago) so I can't ask him.

The story is about a boy who was raised by a robot. Later in the plot it turns out he has a brother (also raised by a robot) who has become evil. Then they fight against each other...

Comment: Do you have any more information? Name of the robots or brothers, number of episodes or movie, anything about the setting?

Comment: not at all - sry - that`s probably why i couldn`t find it until now.

Comment: I understand you don't remember much.  Unfortunately, I think this community might *need* a little bit more.  Even a tiny scrap of a detail might be enough for someone to be able to pick up the ball and run with it.  Let me try to help with these questions: What do you mean "fight"?  Were there weapons involved?  Did the robots look like C3PO or R2D2 or a [mecha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mecha)?

Comment: (or, just for some more examples, Data of Star Trek:TNG (adult Android), or [Rosie from the Jetsons](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=jetsons+rosie)?)

Answer (score 3):

I found this question via Google while looking for an anime with the plot point of a protagonist raised by a robot. The anime I was thinking of was [Genesis Survivor Gaiarth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genesis_Survivor_Gaiarth).

A 1992 three-episode OVA series, the protagonist is raised by a soldier robot who wants to keep the boy safe from war. But war catches up with them.

This does not have the brother element as near as I can tell, and the time doesn't line up, so I don't think it's what you're looking for, but maybe you misremembered some?

Another series with a child raised by robots is Space Family Carlvinson, though that's much more light-hearted.